# Express.js app stops without PM2 restarting it

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I have an Express JS app that is run using PM2 behind a NGINX proxy. It works fine, except for when we send a push notification to all users and the server probably gets too much load. The problem though is that the app just hangs when this happens. Nginx logs reports Connection Refused, Timeouts. My express app doesn't report any errors when this happens so I can't really find what is happening when it hangs. PM2 doesn't restart the app automatically.

It kind of feels like there is a promise that's not getting resolved or rejected, but I have no proof of this. It's just a feeling. Also, should this be logged somewhere? Node usually warns that this will be different in the future.

I know my description is generic, but does anyone have any experience in similar problems? Or maybe can guide me how to find out more why it breaks?

```
Node 12,
Express 4,
Postgres 9,
pg-promise,
Nginx,
Ubuntu Linux
```

Comment: Can you post ~/.pm2/pm2.log file content?

Comment: 2019-11-27T15:50:42: PM2 log: App [api:5] starting in -cluster mode-
2019-11-27T15:50:42: PM2 log: App [api:4] online
2019-11-27T15:50:42: PM2 log: App [api:5] online

# Above is the last deploy and restart. Below when I restarted after hang.

2019-11-28T10:26:00: PM2 log: Stopping app:api id:0
2019-11-28T10:26:00: PM2 log: Stopping app:api id:3
2019-11-28T10:26:01: PM2 log: pid=30211 msg=failed to kill - retrying in 100ms
2019-11-28T10:26:01: PM2 log: pid=30233 msg=failed to kill - retrying in 100ms
2019-11-28T10:26:01: PM2 log: pid=30211 msg=failed to kill - retrying in 100ms

Comment: Refer to this https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2843

Comment: Refer to this one also https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2540